# Deactivating Google plus account and reactivation

Tags: google-plus

If I've deactivated my Google+ account can I reactivate it again and continue with all the previous information, eg. circles and posts?

Can I unblock my self is someone blocked me?

If I deactivate my account, will I be able to get rid of that unblocking thing if I reactivated it again?

Answer (score 3):

Once you deactivate your Google+ profile, all your posts will be deleted and also you will lose all your circles and reactivating does not help recovering that information.

Only those who followed you before deactivating will still be following you automatically after reactivating your profile.

If someone has blocked you, you can't do anything about that and that person should decide to unblock you, and after reactivating your profile you are still blocked by that person.(Couldn't find this in documentation, but this is what happened after I reactivated my Google+ profile, so it's based on personal experience)

Here is official documentation about what happens when you block someone:
https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047934?hl=en

Comment: This seems reasonable, but do you have any further information from Google's documentation to back up the final paragraph?

Comment: @jonsca No, this is just based on personal experience. And before posting my answer here, I asked some friends who recently deactivated and reactivated their Google+ profiles multiple times, so I'm pretty sure at the moment this is what G+ acts like but again it's all personal experience.

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for trying.  I'll let this stand.